# How to change screen index after sliding the tab? flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs

i am using tabbar view with my app that have same floating action button:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () async{
        print("this is the current Screen :$currentScreen");
        if(currentScreen==0)
        {
          await showInformationDialog(context);
        }
        else
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddNewVehical(1),
            ),
          );
      },
```

but when i tap on tab it works perfectly and the currentscreen variable changes from 0 to 1 as expected but problem arises **when i slide from one tab to another the currentscreen variable print always zero due to which on the other tab it also shows dialogue**

can anyone tell me why this is happening? and a solution for it ?
Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TabController` listener in `initState()`.

```
 _tabController!.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
```

In `_handleTabSelection` method, get the `tabController` index.

```
  currentScreen = _tabController!.index;
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to define name '_tabController'.

Comment: How you implement tabBar view? Can you post the screen's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabController. With the index property you can get the currentIndex.
reference : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html